# How to lock android screen orientation

Tags: android

I'm making an Android video player.It has a function like that user can watch video in any orientation.I just use code as follow:

```
Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION, 1);
```

It works, but when I add a function that user can lock the orientation, I just did it:

```
Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION, 0);
```

So I met some trouble. when I'm in landscape orientation and try to lock the orientation, the screen just turns to portrait.
Can anyone solve it or tell me another way to do with it?

Answer (score 2):

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

OR

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

More info here: [Developing Orientation-Aware Android Applications](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/40792)

Comment: but landscape is not only one, it has a reverse direction.Am I right?

Comment: yes, for portrait will be `ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT`

Comment: But it still can change the window direction by rotate 180°.

Answer (score 2):

Use following code Based up on your condition change if else statement

```
int currentOrientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
if (currentOrientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) 
     {
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
     }
 else {
     setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT);
       }
```

or

you can set anyone landscape or portrait in your activity.its never change during the screen rotation

```
<activity android:name="MyActivity"
 android:screenOrientation="landscape"
 android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
  ...
</activity>
```

Comment: Your code works but not completely, When I'm in landscape.with you code, it keeps the landscape orientation. but when I reverse my phone, the orientation is also reversed but not locked.

Comment: maybe you don't understand my meaning. I should provide a button to user that they can open the rotate function or not. so the update answer is not useful,too.

Comment: I actually did it and it performs as my first comment.

Answer (score 1):

In your AndroidManifest.xml, for each activity put

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

It forces the activity to landscape.

Comment: It's a way to keep the orientation.But I can't do that.

Comment: you can learn it from here [link](http://eigo.co.uk/labs/lock-screen-orientation-in-android/) @dieyidezui

Comment: @RahmatAryanto this isn't what he wants. He needs the app to remain in landscape even if the orientation is locked!

Comment: @dmsherazi i know, i'll edit it but i give him [link](http://eigo.co.uk/labs/lock-screen-orientation-in-android/) to help.

Answer (score 0):

just you have ot add following property in you manifest.xml file.

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

like this way,

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
```

That.sit

Comment: Sorry, I don't want t to lock the orientation all the time.

Comment: I can open the rotation function or not. when they close rotation and the screen orientation will not change.

Comment: this isn't what he wants. He needs the app to remain in landscape even if the orientation is locked!

Answer (score 0):

You can request ScreenOrinentation  [`public void setRequestedOrientation (int requestedOrientation)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ActivityInfo.html#screenOrientation). You can use it like this

```
// For landscape
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
 //OR for portrait 
 setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT); 
//OR reverse landscape
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE);
 //OR for reverse portrait
 setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT);
```

> **[requestedOrientation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ActivityInfo.html#screenOrientation)** An orientation constant as used in ActivityInfo.screenOrientation.
>
> Added in API level 1
>   The preferred screen orientation this activity would like to run in. From the screenOrientation attribute, one of SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED, SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE, SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT, SCREEN_ORIENTATION_USER, SCREEN_ORIENTATION_BEHIND, SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR, SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR, SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE, SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT, SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE, SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT, SCREEN_ORIENTATION_FULL_SENSOR, SCREEN_ORIENTATION_USER_LANDSCAPE, SCREEN_ORIENTATION_USER_PORTRAIT, SCREEN_ORIENTATION_FULL_USER, SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LOCKED,